# Issues with MID$ function

Tags: basic, commodore

I'm trying to print out every character of a given string on a new line.

```
1 INPUT ""; A$
2 E%=0
3 IF E% < LEN(A$) GOTO 5
4 END
5 PRINT MID$(A$,E%,E%+1)
6 E% = E% + 1
7 GOTO 3
```

I keep on getting

> ILLEGAL QUANTITY ERROR IN 5

and I don't know why.

Comment: Which "BASIC" is this? There are 100s. Where are your line numbers? They should be included when posting code.

Comment: I'm using BASIC V2

Comment: On what type and version of computer system? Using which program to write the code?

Comment: I'm using a VIC-20 emulator, writing in the kernal

Answer (score 1):

You have three problems with your code, two of them related.

First, E% should start at 1 not 0.
Second, because E% starts at 1, you chould check for <= instead of <.
Finally, your MID$() function parameters should be as below:

```
1 INPUT ""; A$
2 E%=1
3 IF E% <= LEN(A$) GOTO 5
4 END
5 PRINT MID$(A$,E%,1)
6 E% = E% + 1
7 GOTO 3
```

Next you should look into FOR/NEXT loops.